# How to reveal the 8 surrounding cells of an empty cell in Minesweeper

Tags: java, arrays, minesweeper

I have a recursion method for a mineSweeper but I would like to write a loop for when the cell is empty, which should reveal the 8 cells surrounding the empty one by recursion, how do I do it?

This is the reveal method I have:

```
void reveal(int x,int y,char[][] mineField,boolean[][] isVisible){
    System.out.println(x + "  " + y);
    if(x<0 || x>=mineField.length   ||   y<0 || y>mineField[0].length){

        return;
    }

    if(mineField[x][y] == '*'){ 
        isGameOver = true; // there is a bomb, stop game.
        return;
    }
    if(mineField[x][y] == '1'||mineField[x][y] == '2'){ // how do I make it any number (1-8) instead of 1 or 2
        isVisible[x][y] = true;
        return;
    }

    if(mineField[x][y] == '.'){
        isVisible[x][y] = true;

                reveal(i,j, mineField, isVisible); // how do I write a method here to reveal the 8 surrounding cells?

    }
}
```

and this is my print method:

```
void printMineMap(char[][] mineField,boolean[][] isVisible){
    for(int i=0; i<mineField.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<mineField[0].length; j++){
            if(isVisible[i][j]=true)
                System.out.println(" "+mineField[i][j]+" ");
            else if(isVisible[i][j]=false)
                System.out.println("[ ]");
        }
        System.out.println("  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should also post plain English logic for how spaces are revealed in minesweeper.  I just played online, and it's not at all obvious how tiles get revealed with each step.  This comment is significant, because I'm leaving open the possibility that your entire code may need to be refactored.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over all fields with a coordinate difference of at most 1 in x and y direction to the current field.

```
for (int i = x-1; i <= x+1; i++) {
    for (int j = y-1; j <= y+1; j++) {
        reveal(i,j, mineField, isVisible);
    }
}
```

However, you don't want to reveal fields that are already visible in order to avoid an infinite recursion. So add this at the beginning of the reveal method but after the check if x and y is in range:

```
if (isVisible[x][y]) {
    return;
}
```